# Redux-Saga is not waiting for action to complete using redux-saga-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga-firebase package to do some firebase/auth actions, but the problem is that code after dispatch is executed before the dispatch is finished.
For example:

```
dispatch({ type: 'SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_REQUESTED', email: 'test@test.com', password: 'qwerty123@'})
console.log(`propsUser: ${this.props.user.currentUser}`);
```

Saga.js

```
function* signInWithEmailAndPassword(data) {
  try {
   const user = yield call(reduxSagaFirebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword, data.email, data.password);
   yield put({ type: SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED, currentUser: user });
  }
  catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_FAILED, message: error.message });
  }
}


export default function* userRootSaga() {
  //yield fork(syncUserSaga)
  yield all([
    takeLatest(SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_REQUESTED, signInWithEmailAndPassword),
  ])
}
```

reducer

```
case SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED:
     console.log(`action: ${Object.values(action)}`); //here I get the correct user the second time
     return { ...state, currentUser: action.currentUser }
```

in that scenario, the first time when I press the button this.props.user.currentUser is undefined, but if I press it again two-three seconds after that I get the user object.
How can I wait for the action to finish before put the call to reducer?

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: The saga that gets invoked by dispatch works asnyc (I guess, since you hit firebase, which is on another server). So if you want to wait for the user to be logged in, you have to wait for the `SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED` action. The best way is to check for a valid `state.currentUser` in your component.

Comment: but how can I continue execution only if I have a valid object? should I check in a while loop or what can I do?

Comment: Are you using React? You can just render a "fallback" or "loading" component, while your're hitting firebase. Something like `return user ? <Profile user={user} /> : <Loading />`, or however you like to do it (assuming these components are defined).

Answer (score 0):

```
case SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_REQUESTED:
     return { ...state, isLoading: true, isLoaded: false }

case SIGNIN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_REQUESTED:
     return { ...state, isLoading: false, isLoaded: true, currentUser: action.currentUser }
```

And then You need to render the login button like:

```
<LoginButton disabled={isLoading}>
```